# Return in just one lines

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem, I have a query in postgresql and I need to do a SUM, however, it returns me a total of 4 lines because the ids of my routes are different, and I need to add the "totalChecklists" and return the amount of all in one line.

```
select "users"."id",
        count((cycles.adherence >= 100 and cycles.justified = false) or null) as "routesDone",
        count((cycles.adherence < 100 and cycles.opened = false) or null) as "routesNotDone", 
        count((cycles.opened = true and cycles.adherence < 100) or null) as "routesOpened", 
        count(cycles.justified or null) as "routesJustified",
        routes."totalSpots" AS "totalCheck",
        count(cycles.id) as "routesOnPeriod",
        (
             count((cycles.adherence >= 100 and cycles.justified = false) or null) +
             count((cycles.adherence < 100 and cycles.opened = false) or null) +
             count((cycles.opened = true and cycles.adherence < 100) or null) +
             count(cycles.justified or null)
        ) as "routesTotal", 
        0 as "routesDoneLate", 
        0 as "routesLate", 
        SUM(case when cycles.adherence >= 100 then routes."totalAssets" else 0 end) AS "coveredAssets", 
        SUM(case when cycles.adherence < 100 then routes."totalAssets" else 0 end) AS "uncoveredAssets" 
from "routes" 
    inner join "cycles" on "routes"."identifier" = "cycles"."routeIdentifier" 
    inner join "workspaces" on "cycles"."workspaceId" = "workspaces"."id" 
    inner join "users" on "users"."id" = "cycles"."inspectorId" 
where "routes"."deleted_at" is null 
    and "cycles"."deletedAt" is null 
    and "workspaces"."deleted" = false
    and "cycleStartAt" <= '2022-07-11T02:59:59Z' 
    and "cycleEndAt" >= '2022-04-12T03:00:00Z'
    and "users"."id" = 'b67830a7-39fc-4ad5-bf26-07a43dcd3676'
    and "routes"."contextPath" like '/malicious-interaction-murder-32%'
    and "routes"."deleted_at" is null
group by 
    users.id,
    routes.id
```

My return:
[image]

Sorry for my bad english, I hope I managed to be very clear.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: what if you just stop grouping by `routes.id`? (note that you will have to sum `routes."totalSpots"`)

Comment: In advance, for trying to help me Tryph.
If I stop bundling I get this error:

column "routes.totalSpots" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Yep, that is why I mentionned in my last comment that you have to sum the `routes."totalSpots"` field, try to simply replace it with `SUM(routes."totalSpots")`. Each field which is not passed to an aggregation function have to appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, so if you aggregate the `routes."totalSpots"`, you won't need to group by it anymore.

Comment: Tryph, I managed to solve it by doing a sub-query, thanks a lot for the help! See you soon